# how does stoppropagation works with Loops?

Tags: javascript, c#, foreach, stoppropagation

i create some Tiles in a foreach loop:

```
        @foreach (var a in Model.AA)
        {
            <partial name="Partial/A/Tile" model="a" />
        }
```

each of this Tiles have a Button to Start something. (Yes if the JS works i dont need the asp calls at the button)

my Problem is now: The js call works only at the first Tile but not at all others. But Why?

Button

```
<div class="Infos" Id=@Model.Id>
   <a class="button" id="startsomething" url="@Url.Action(nameof(AController.Start), "A")" asp-action="Start" asp-route-Id="@Model.Id">Start me</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $('#startsomething').click(function (event) {
        var Id = $(this).parents('.Infos').attr('Id');
        var url = $(this).attr('url');
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        Start(url, Id)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

ids are meant to be unique, so the event only registers to one id when you use `#startsomething`. Use a class name, and the selector `.somethingClass`.